# integer in regex literal constructor?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm confused by the syntax of how the regex is constructed below. I understand the . and the {} but I'm confused by everything inside there.

Here is the regex. k is a variable assigned to a positive integer.

```
RegExp(".{"+k+"}", "g");
```

In case it helps this evaluates to `/.{k}/g` (k is the integer that was passed in for k). I can't piece together why though.

How can double quotes be placed inside double quotes and why are they needed? What are the two plus signs doing?

EDIT: I feel really silly about asking this now. I think the lack of spaces in the string through me off.

Comment: *"How can double quotes be placed inside double quotes"* - They're not. There is one string, `".{"`, then `+k+`, then another string `"}"`. The plus signs concatenate the three pieces together to form a single string, `".{2}"` (if `k` was `2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor can take in 2 string arguments (as is the case in your example): 1 for the pattern itself and 1 for the flags. The "+" is a JavaScript string concatenation operator among other things. The quotes in your example signify string boundaries and are not parts of the strings themselves. `"a"+c+"b"` translates to string `"a"`, concatenated with variable `c` converted to string, concatenated with string `"b"`.